# Run script while installing war file in Grails

Tags: grails, installation, war

Is it possible to run some sort of script during the installation of a Grails war file?

For example, I would like to copy my app's Config.groovy file to our Tomcat server's conf folder during the installation. This way it can be used as an external config file (instead of having to manually create it and move it there every time). Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use the BootStrap to do that. When your app is initializing, check if you are in the Tomcat (catalina.home prop) and if the file not exists, create.

```
class BootStrap {
  def init = {
    if(grails.util.Environment.warDeployed) {
       String homeFolder = System.getProperty('catalina.home')
       if(homeFolder) {
         File externalConfigFile = new File("$homeFolder/conf/MyAppConfig.groovy")
         if(!externalConfigFile.exists()) {
           externalConfigFile.createNewFile()
         }
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked beautifully. Thank you!